# chartjs and webpack in Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack

I try to test chartjs with symfony UX but I have error console for import files css and js after launch command

> npm run build

errors is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRNEP.png)

file base.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %} {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }} {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %} {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }} {% endblock %}
        
    </body>
</html>
```

also chart of chartJS is not display

Answer (score 0):

i've made somethink who looks like but with PieChart.js.
First, check your webpack.config.yml file. Me, i've created a js file only for chart:

```yaml
Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .enableSassLoader()
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .addEntry('charts', './assets/js/charts.js')
;
```

Then, the js (i simplify) :

```js
import chartist from 'chartist';

;(function(c) {

    const init = () => {
       // all js to build the chart
    };

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        init();
    });
}(chartist));
```

My template :

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('charts') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Check if your JS is compiled (with `yarn encore dev` command) in public directory (`./public` if symfony 4 or symfony 5, `./web` if symfony 3.4 and less)
Check if your library is installed in node_modules directory. Then check your webpack config, check the compilation too.

If compilation is OK, charts.js will be in `public/build/charts.js`.

Symfony source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html and https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html (with example)
Hope this is will be helpfull :).